# Curl request - could not resolve host: "password"

Tags: curl, post, cmd

I am trying to send a curl POST request using the windows `cmd` prompt. Below is the code sample:

```
curl -i -X POST 
https://localhost:4119/api/sessions
--insecure
-H Cache-Control:no-cache
-H Content-Type:application/json
-H api-version:v1 
-c cookie.txt
-d '{
\"userName\":\"username\",
\"password\":\"password123!\"
}'
```

I am using `\` to escape `"` in the string.

The error returned by `curl` is: (6) Could not resolve host: "password"

What is wrong with the example?

Using:

- Windows Server 2012 R2
- Curl 7.46.0
- CMD prompt

Comment: You're using `'` (single quote) for `-d` parameter's data. Use double quotes.

Comment: The line continuation character for cmd.exe .bat file scripts is a CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT `^`. Also called a caret.